# Positioning element next to another in SVG

Tags: svg

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

The number should be centered horizontally in the middle, and the percentage symbol should be shown next to it.

I'd prefer not to hardcode any values, especially since I've got similar use cases to this where what I want to center is user defined text and not just a number with one or two digits. I could read the metrics of the .percentage container using JavaScript, but users will be able to choose their own webfont and I'd prefer to do this purely in SVG if possible instead of having to deal with detecting when the webfont has finished loading.

This is what I've got so far:

```css
.percentage__value {
  font-size: 80px;
}

.percentage__symbol {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="260" height="260">
  <g >
    <path
        fill="skyblue"
        transform="translate(130,130)"
        d="M0,130A130,130 0 1,1 0,-130A130,130 0 1,1 0,130M0,105A105,105 0 1,0 0,-105A105,105 0 1,0 0,105Z">
    </path>
    <path stroke="purple" d="M130 0 v 260 Z" stroke-width="2px"></path>
    <text class="percentage" x="130" y="130" text-anchor="middle">
      <tspan class="percentage__value" alignment-baseline="middle">93</tspan>
      <tspan class="percentage__symbol" alignment-baseline="middle">%</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

If I were to do this using HTML and CSS I'd just do something like:

```
.percentage {
  position: relative;
}

.percentage__symbol {
  position: absolute;
  ...
}
```

One hacky way I can solve this is to add a .percentage__symbol on either side of the number and hide the first one, but that breaks text selection.

I'm using d3.js to generate the SVG, in case that's useful.

Comment: Make the hidden % pointer-events: none to fix selection.

Comment: That only solves the selection problem if I initiate the selection directly from the hidden percentage symbol. In any case, I'm after a robust solution here that I can apply in other situations I encounter with SVG.

Comment: You're going to need to use javascript then.

Comment: in d3 you can use `getBBox()` to get the bounding box, then you can calculate the position of `%`

Answer (score 1):

The attribute `alignment-baseline` is not supported by many browsers. But what you can do: define a horizontal path and enclose the `tspan` element with `textPath` element, defining the `startOffset="50%"` for the first `tspan` and e.g. 70% for the second one.

See http://jsfiddle.net/2e7opjxe/1/

There is another solution without `textPath`, just define the `x,y` coordinates for both `tspan` elements.

See http://jsfiddle.net/2e7opjxe/3/

Comment: That's still a bit to close to hardcoded px values for my taste. 70% may look ok in one font but not a more narrow one.

Comment: yes, it is hardcoded, you can define css with matrix transformation for the path the textPath is referencing to. then you can use e.g. 100% for the *%* position. when you redesign your svg to have [0,0] in the middle, scaleX would be sufficient. because of poor support of `alignment-baseline` you would have to remove the attribute and find a suitable horizontal position for the path. welcome to the world of svg ;-)

Comment: btw the same issue for 1% and 99.99% in the same font